# avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout, RX leds not blinking

Tags: arduino

I can't upload any program to my arduino using the arduino IDE and a USB cable.

When I try to, it says `avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout`

I've search all the web and look at questions like [avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645441/avrdude-stk500v2-receivemessage-timeout) but my arduino led aren't blinking when I try to upload a program.

I've crafted something using my RasberryPi and arvdude to flash the bootloader again. [Here are some pictures of my setup.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlT1m.jpg)

I'm using this command:

```
sudo avrdude -p atmega2560 -C ~/avrdude_gpio.conf -c pi_1 -v -U flash:w:stk500boot_v2_mega2560.hex:i
```

Here is the output of my attempt:

```
avrdude: Version 6.1, compiled on Jul  7 2015 at 10:29:47
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/home/pi/avrdude_gpio.conf"
         User configuration file is "/root/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : unknown
         Using Programmer              : pi_1
         AVR Part                      : ATmega2560
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PA0
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    10     8    0 no       4096    8      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           flash         65    10   256    0 yes    262144  256   1024  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : linuxgpio
         Description     : Use the Linux sysfs interface to bitbang GPIO lines
         Pin assignment  : /sys/class/gpio/gpio{n}
           RESET   =  19
           SCK     =  26
           MOSI    =  20
           MISO    =  16

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e9801
avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as FF
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as D8
avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as FD
avrdude: NOTE: "flash" memory has been specified, an erase cycle will be performed
         To disable this feature, specify the -D option.
avrdude: erasing chip
avrdude: reading input file "stk500boot_v2_mega2560.hex"
avrdude: writing flash (261406 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 6.24s

avrdude: 261406 bytes of flash written
avrdude: verifying flash memory against stk500boot_v2_mega2560.hex:
avrdude: load data flash data from input file stk500boot_v2_mega2560.hex:
avrdude: input file stk500boot_v2_mega2560.hex contains 261406 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip flash data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 11.71s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 261406 bytes of flash verified

avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as FF
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as D8
avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as FD
avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK (E:FD, H:D8, L:FF)

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

It all seems good, but when I reconnect it to my computer (on Linux), I can't upload any program.

The board is correctly detected, as /dev/ttyACM0. When I `Get board info` from the Tools menu, here is the output

```
BN: Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560
VID: 2341
PID: 0042
SN: 754393236353518131F2
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: For this kind of issue I would suggest posting to http://arduino.stackexchange.com/ , you're more likely to get a fast reply.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin ok, i'll try that, thanks